# How can I fix OSError [Errno 2] when installing PyTorch using pip?

Tags: pytorch, command-prompt, torch, torchvision

I could not install `torch` due to an OSError:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The error code I received after inputting `pip install torch` was this:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:  'C:\\Users\\T0926727H\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\torch\\include\\ATen\\ops\\_fake_quantize_per_tensor_affine_cachemask_tensor_qparams_compositeexplicitautograd_dispatch.h'
```

Would appreciate the help!

I read through the answers given and tried out this `pip install torch --user` instead of `pip install torch`.
Despite this working for many others, it still did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're hitting the Windows 10 path character limit, which is 260 characters. Your path name is 275 characters. I would recommend either shortening that, or going into regedit to enable long path names. But just a warning, **messing around with regedit can sometimes have machine-breaking level consequences**. I avoid it whenever possible.

> To enable long file paths in Windows, open Registry Editor, create a
> new DWORD named "LongPathsEnabled" in
> "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" and
> set the value to 1. Pro and Enterprise users can enable "Enable Win32
> Long Paths" in the Local Group Policy Editor.

<sup>From https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/.</sup>

I think you might have installed Python through the Microsoft store. If you uninstall Python, then [install Python from the Python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/), your path name will be much shorter, and you'll probably be able to install `pytorch` without editing the registry.